# A system of nonlinear recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations, nonlinear-system

Please help me solve a recurrence relation system. I can solve simple recurrence relations, but don’t know how to solve it.

$\begin{cases}x_n = x_{n-1} - \frac{(-1)^n a y_{n-1}}{\sqrt{x_{n-1}^2 + y_{n-1}^2}}\\y_n = y_{n-1} + \frac{(-1)^n a x_{n-1}}{\sqrt{x_{n-1}^2 + y_{n-1}^2}}\end{cases}$

Where $x_0$, $y_0$, $a$ are real numbers.

I also need to find the limit of these sequences such as:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2}}\\\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{y_n}{\sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2}}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you add some details as to where this problem comes from and if you already know of a geometric interpretation? Thanks.

Comment: The problem arose when writing the engine for the game. We have a 2d vector which at each step is added up with the current normalized vector, rotated at each step either 90 or -90 degrees. I need to find the limit to which he is going. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Any information about $a$ or $x_0\choose y_0$?

Comment: $a$ is a parameter that is an real number and takes values ​​from 0 to 30. $x_0$, $y_0$ are the initial values ​​of the vector, which are real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_n = x_n + i y_n$.  Then your system can be written as
$$ z_{n+1} = z_n (1 + (-1)^n a i/|z_n|)$$
In particular, assuming $a$ is real, $$
|z_{n+1}| = |z_n| \sqrt{1+a^2/|z_n|^2}$$
I'll assume $a \ne 0$ and $z_0 \ne 0$.  Then $|z_n|$ is an increasing sequence.
If it had a finite limit $L$, then we'd have $L = L \sqrt{1+a^2/L^2}$, 
and it's easy to see that this has no solution.
Thus $|z_n| \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for not providing some details in advance. I needed to find the limit of the unit vector, like $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2}}\\\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{y_n}{\sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2}}$$